# Cannot find textblock in Xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, textblock

**Problem**

Below is my code. I am using it to find textBlocks in a dataGrid.

```
foreach (TextBlock tb in FindVisualChildren<TextBlock>(dataGrid))
{
    // do something
}
```

```
private static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (depObj != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
            if (child != null && child is T)
            {
                yield return (T)child;
            }

            foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
            {
                yield return childOfChild;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, The problem is that I cannot find all TextBlocks in DataGrid.

I doubt that it's because the xaml haven't fully loaded.

Since the textBlocks which are unable to be found are those not being written in xaml in the beginning. They are added to dataGrid by user in running time.

**Current Solution**

I am using Dispatcher to make sure dataGrid is fully loaded, but I think it's too slow and sometimes it will produce strange bugs.

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Loaded, new Action(() => {
    foreach (TextBlock tb in FindVisualChildren<TextBlock>(dataGrid))
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

**Question**

I want to know whether there are other solutions which can make sure dataGrid is fully loaded.
Maybe there are some techniques I can make dataGrid load first?

Thanks in advance.

**XAML**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGridArguments" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="12" BorderBrush="#FFC1C6C8" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#FFC1C6C8" VerticalGridLinesBrush="#FFC1C6C8" HeadersVisibility="Column" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="Cell" BorderThickness="1" Background="White" CanUserResizeRows="False" EnableRowVirtualization="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserAddRows="False" RowHeight="20" MouseRightButtonUp="dataGridArguments_MouseRightButtonUp" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ArgumentName}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Argument Name"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ArgumentValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Argument Value" MaxWidth="400"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Can you share your XAML code?

Comment: 1. If you are adding the textboxes manually at run time, why don'y you maintain the references to textboxes when you add.
2. you can subscribe to Loaded event of datagrid and perform your logic there.

Comment: @GaurangDave sure

Comment: @swamy 1. Because I have more than one page, each page have several textblocks and user may delete or add at any time. I think it's really hard to maintain all of them. 2. Ok, I'll give it a try.

Comment: @B.H.Chiang, why is it necessary to find all those TextBlocks? what is your purpose?

Comment: @ASh I am adding find&replace feature to my application. So I want to find those blocks and check the text content inside.

Comment: @B.H.Chiang, can't you do that with bound data?

Comment: @ASh I haven't thought about that.....I should give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: Ash has suggested what I was about to. You should (almost ) never work with a datagrid via all it's controls as you are trying to. It's the case of absolute last resort. Even then there is probably a better way.

Comment: @Andy I got it. Thanks!